# use docker to use deep learning server

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nvidia

Let say I have a

```
ServerA(4gpus)
ServerB(4gpus)
ServerC(4gpus)
```

Is it possible to use docker use all this 12gpu together? 
which keyword should I search to make this happen and is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes and OpenShift should be able to do this, assuming that you have the right drivers, supported devices, ... Definitely not GA.

Look for Kubernetes in combination with GPU computing, GPU scheduling, GPU passthrough, ...

Nvidia does provide [a device plugin, and more generally an operator](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-gpu-operator-simplifying-gpu-management-in-kubernetes/), that should help you integrate your GPU as compute resources in a Kubernetes cluster.